# java decimal format not rounding correctly

Tags: java, double

I have this code

```
private static DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat(".00");
System.out.println(df2.format(14.3445));
```

the correct answer for this should be 14.35
but i get 14.34
Why ?

The conversion should be 14.3445 -> 14.345 -> 14.35

Comment: No. 14.3445 -> 14.34 is OK.

Comment: why do you assume it should round like 14.3445 -> 14.345 -> 14.35 ? I think the @JacekCz is right

Comment: You can use rounding mode: `df2.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the API https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

> ## Rounding
>
> DecimalFormat provides rounding modes defined in RoundingMode for formatting. By default, it uses RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN.

and  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_EVEN

> ## public static final RoundingMode HALF_EVEN
>
> Rounding mode to round towards the "nearest neighbor" unless both neighbors are equidistant, in which case, round towards the even neighbor. Behaves as for RoundingMode.HALF_UP if the digit to the left of the discarded fraction is odd; behaves as for RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN if it's even.

Since the second 4 (third fraction digit) is even it is not changed which leads to "round down" for the second fraction digit.

Answer (score 3):

14.34 is correct, as it is closer to 14.3445 that 14.35:

|14.3445 - 14.34| = 0.0045

while

|14.3445 - 14.35| = 0.0055